# Android : ImageView With Complete Zoom functions

Tags: android, imageview

I searched the internet and StackOverflow for this but none of the answers were complete.

I need and ImageView with complete zoom functions like :

1. Zoom and pan with double click
2. Zoom and pan with multi touch (move fingers in any direction ... not just horizontal and vertical)
3. Scroll horizontally and vertically simultaneously like if I move my finger from bottom left to top right it scrolls in both horizontal and vertical direction
4. Setting bitmap (Java)
5. Setting drawable (Java and Xml)
6. Setting initial scale (for example with matrix)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code

Comment: Yes, so where else I can ask such questions. 

and I think there must be a code written before.

Comment: That's not the purpose of stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView. I hope this will help you.